# Geoserver is getting blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: linux, nginx, content-security-policy, geoserver

I have installed GeoServer on my linux machine and is running behind Nginx proxy. GeoServer web interface is working fine. But when I try to create a new store, it is not working. When I click on the "browse" button a modal is opened. That is when the error message is printed on to the console, which says

[CSP error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pFTW.png)

```
Wicket.Ajax:  Wicket.Ajax.Call.processEvaluation: Exception evaluating javascript: EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP, text: (function(){var e =
```

What to add to my content security policy to get this to work? I have added my domain here as well. But that did not work either.

Here is my CSP:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "base-uri 'self'; default-src 'self'; img-src https 'self' https://amazon-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ data:; object-src 'none'; require-trusted-types-for 'script'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://unpkg.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://unpkg.com; font-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://unpkg.com";
```

UPDATE:

I noticed this TrustedHTML assignment error on chrome

```
This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.
```

[TrustedHTML assignment error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX20v.png)

Comment: do you actually see your header in nginx response?

Comment: @user973254 Yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error you'll need to add 'unsafe-eval' to script-src. But note that for each 'unsafe-*' you add the value of your CSP decreases.

TrustedHTML doesn't allow setting innerHTML, use textContent instead if you are setting unformatted text. Otherwise you should be using DOMPurify or some other methods ensure that html is trusted.

Comment: Is there any other secure way to handle the first issue? I am using third party library "geoserver", in which the innerHTML is being set. I do not have control over it to use DOMPurify. It is working if I rename Content-Security-Policy to Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only, but again this is not secure.

Comment: For the first issue you'll need to stop using eval(), setInterval, setTimout and new Function(). You'll need to rewrite them in some way, see also https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#eval_too. If you can't replace geoserver you will likely need to remove "require-trusted-types-for 'script';" from your CSP.